# In php I'm able to download excel file, but when I use same code in codeigniter it's directly sending HTML content instead of downloading XLS file?

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

```php
    <?php
    $data1 ='<div id="prnittab">
    <table width="100%" style="font-size:13px; margin-top:11px;border:solid 1px #333333;border- 
    bottom: 0px;">
    <tr>
        <td width="100%" style="padding:20px;">
            <table width="100%" style="border:0px;">
                <tr>
       <td width=20% height="5px;" colspan="2"><img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/640/360"
                            width="220" height="75" alt="logo" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" height="10"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
     <td width="50%" align="left" valign="top style="font-size:16px;font-weight:bold;padding-left:15px;">Report Data</td>
                    <td width="50%" align="right" valign="top"
    style="font-size:12px;font-weight:bold;padding-right:15px;">Monday, September 23, 2019</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <table width="100%" style="border-collapse: collapse;border: 1px solid #333333;">
    <tr height="30">
    <td align="left" style="font-size:12px;font-size:12px;font-weight:bold;padding-left:10px;">XYZ</td>
    <td align="left"
      style="font-size:12px;font-size:12px;font-weight:bold;height:20px !important;padding-right:10px;">Check
        </td>
   <td align="right"
        style="font-size:12px;font-size:12px;font-weight:bold;height:20px !important;padding-right:10px;">
            $540.00</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </div>';
    header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file");
    echo $data1;
```

Comment: Is CodeIgniter sending headers already? That should result in a warning from PHP: `Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /some/file.php:12) in /some/file.php on line 23`.
By the way: What exactly are you trying to do here? It looks like you're sending HTML code as an Excel file?!

Comment: Yeah. If I keep above code in some php file, and if i run it, it's automatically downloading the XL file. But if I keep code in codeigniter function it's returning html code instead of downloading XL file directly.

Comment: My Controller Class Header Part is ::::::header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, PUT, DELETE');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
ini_set('memory_limit', '2048M');
use Restserver\Libraries\REST_Controller;
require APPPATH . 'libraries/REST_Controller.php';

Comment: Class is ::::::::::
class Reports extends REST_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
        public function saveReportexcel_get()
    {
        $id = $_GET['id'];
        $file = $id . ".xls";
        $data1 ="Above html code goes here";
        header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file");
        echo $data1;
    }
}